# How to write into a first-order logic formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

For the prime numbers, I wrote the following definitons:(one of the definition has to be the "general definition of the prime numbers" and the other is based on the theorem of irreducible elements).I have to find 2 formulas which have one free variable and the domain are the integers. Are my formulas correct?

irreducible number(or irreducible element?):

if $ \ge 2$

$ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}:p=ab \implies(p=a  ,$ or $ p=b) $

prime number:

if $ \ge 2$

$ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}:p|ab \implies(p|a  ,$ or $ p|b) $ (where $|$ is the notation of divisibility)

How to write in first order logic(so with formalization)the following: "Any prime is irreducible"?

Comment: Just mathematically, what is an irreducible number?

Comment: I'm not sure how to say it in English, "I wrote the mathematical definiton of it"

Comment: I would say that the more general definition of rpime is that its only divisors are 1 and itself (and the number itself greater or equal 2 of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that $p$ is prime iff

$$p \ge 2 \land  \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}:p=ab \implies(a=1  \lor  a=p) $$

So with $p$ irreducible number iff

$$ p \ge 2 \land \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}:p=ab \implies(p=a \lor p=b) $$

You can express the claim that any prime is irreducible like this:

$$\forall p \in \mathbb{N}: ('Prime(p)' \Rightarrow 'Irreducible(p)')$$

, i.e.:

$$\forall p \in \mathbb{N}: (p \ge 2 \land  \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}:p=ab \implies(a=1  \lor  a=p)) \Rightarrow ( p \ge 2 \land \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}:p=ab \implies(p=a \lor p=b) )$$